# Weird artifacts appeared in eevee because of normal map

Tags: texturing, normal-map, eevee-render-engine, artifacts

I'm was working on a shotgun and suddenly for some reason some weird artifacts appeared on the metal materials.

[image]

I know that removing the image texture and leaving only a noise texture+bump on the normal input makes the artifacts disappear and also I don't see it when rendering in cycles:

[image]

It was working with no problem before. I already tried copying the model to a new file and it didn't work.

the file:
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51576

Comment: You should delete your UV Maps in the Object Data > UV Maps tab.

I think you somehow created UV Maps by accident and since you're not using UV unwrapping you don't need UV Maps.

Comment: Could you please use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for uploading blend files? Stuff on other services tends to vanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delete your UV Maps in the Object Data. Since you're not using UV Map based texturing.

[image: Delete UV Maps in Object Data tab]

Otherwise, you'll get unwanted UV Map data assigned to your mesh. 
Best to just delete them when they're not being used.

[image: No UV map based texturing]

In your case, (as shown in the picture above) because you are not using UV Map based texturing for any part of your model; you should delete the UV Maps for all the parts of the model.

Comment: I was going to use the uv maps to add scratches or written text on the metal but I think I can work around this someway, thx.

Comment: It's still kinda weird that Blender automatically assigns the normal map to be UV based. Even when you change the type of mapping, it stays as UV based mapping. 

You can work around this by deleting the UV Map, but when creating a new UV Map (for like indeed adding scratches or written text); it automatically changes it back to UV based mapping.

Maybe you (or we) should be questioning if there is a way to add a UV map to the mesh, but leaving the mapping for the normal map unassigned, or to be able to change it to a different kind of mapping?